# JNA result character encoding result in UTF8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jna, cyrillic

I'm using JNA to get window data. As you can see below, the result is in a byte array. I need cyrillic characters to be readable but it's not happening at the moment, it just gives back a bunch of question marks. The problem is not with the conversion to String, I have checked the byte array values.

I've tried `System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "UTF-8");` but it looks like it's only useful for Java String inputs, not for outputs.

Code:

```
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, buffer, 512);
String result = Native.toString(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated.

EDIT
Thanks for Technomage. Final solution:

```
char[] buffer = new char[2048];
HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextW(hwnd, buffer, 512);
String result = String.valueOf(buffer).trim();
```

Comment: What _are_ the characters in the returned byte array?  Are you certain it's UTF8 and not windows' default encoding (`windows-1251`)? Have you tried `Native.toString()` with a different encoding? Have you tried `GetWindowTextW()`, which would bypass the problem altogether?

Comment: Solved! Didn't know about GetWindowTextW(), it's not included in the javadoc (neither is GetWindowTextA(), though, only GetWindowText()). Thank you very much!

Comment: The defined `GetWindowText()` mapping actually maps through to `GetWindowTextW()` automatically.  We didn't bother putting in an explicit binding for the ASCII version.